# RewriteRule to step up one level

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following example URL

```
http://myWeb.com/for-sale/whateverCategory/item-title/55
```

I need this to resolve to:

```
http://myWeb.com/pages/for-sale.html?name=test-title&item_id=55
```

This is what I'm trying but it fails:

```
RewriteRule ^for-sale/([^/.]*)/?$ /pages/for-sale.html?name=$1&item_id=$2 [L,QSA]
```

If I add in the `/pages/` level to the URL it works e.g.

```
http://myWeb.com/pages/for-sale/childCat/item-title/55
```

But I want it without the `/pages/`

Any ideas where I am going wrong?

Comment: Where is the htaccess located?

Comment: Web root, same level as `/pages/` folder

Comment: If you want the url without `/pages/` segment ,  use the rule in `/root/.htaccess` instead of using it in  `/pages/.htaccess`

Comment: It's not IN `/pages/` it's at the same level, like `/.htaccess`

Comment: It's really wired. I thought it was in pages.htaccess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rule is not capturing values `$1` and `$2` correctly in the regex.

You can use:

```
RewriteRule ^for-sale/[^/]+/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ /pages/for-sale.html?name=$1&item_id=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks but only works if I have `/pages/` in the URL e.g. `http://myWeb.com/pages/for-sale/childCat/item-title/55` - I ideally want `http://myWeb.com/for-sale/childCat/item-title/55`

Comment: There is a `pages` directory yes, the raw URL is `http://myWeb.com/pages/for-sale.html?name=test-title&item_id=55`

Comment: Do you mean in the `pages` folder? If not, how can I go above? You mean add a random `dir` into `pages` and place it in there?

Comment: Ok, I get you, but there is no parent... web root, where index.html lives, is also where `pages` lives - I'm on a windows environment locally e.g. `c:\mySite\pages\` and  `c:\mySite\.htaccess`

Comment: That is where it lives now as I said earlier, on the same level as `pages` - so I have `c:\mySite\pages` and `c:\mySite\.htaccess`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117016/discussion-between-anubhava-and-darren-sweeney).